# Weird code-signing error

Tags: code-signing, xcode5, provisioning-profile, mac-app-store

I'm trying to upload a new Mac app, designed under Xcode 5, to the Mac App Store. I have done this before for many apps with previous Xcode versions, so I thought I had it mastered, but I am banging my head against this one. It must be some trivial issue, but I don't see what!

Description of my settings:

- My target's "General" settings have "Signing: Mac App Store", then my account as "Team"
- I have sandbox enabled ("Capabilities" tab of the target)
- In "Build Settings", I have:

  - CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = MyApp/MyApp.entitlements
  - CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = Mac Developer
  - PROVISIONING_PROFILE = Mac Team Provisioning Profile: com.myname.myapp

The app builds and runs fine. Yet, when I validate it for App Store distribution, I get the following error:

> Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle MyApp [MyApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the Mac OS Developer Portal.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to check out the iOS code signing issue that is discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors. Apple added a new section to the build settings and you need to change the default. It didn’t work for me, but it worked for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You should review the section in the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582) covering the management of certificates and provisioning profiles for Mac Apps. Specifically the section on [Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW2) will provide the most insight and covers fixes for the provision profile issue you've reported. I recommend you explore the entire troubleshooting area as sometimes certificate expiration dates impact the validity of provisioning profiles.

[image: Invalid Provisioning Profile]