# "Invalid Provisioning Profile... [Missing code-signing certificate.]" for brand new, Vanilla Mac App in OS X Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

In OS X Maverick's XCode, I created a brand new Mac > "Cocoa Application", with Core Data and Spotlight Importerl; about as vanilla a Cocoa application I could muster.

Under Preferences > Accounts, I signed in to my Mac Developer Account.

In Targets > Identity, I set Signing to "Mac App Store", and was able to select my Mac Developer Account for "Team".

I then went to Product > Clean, and then Product > Build for... > Running, and then Produt > Archive.

In the Organizer, I select the resulting .app and click "Validate", and hit the Mac App Store radio, and hit "Next", and it's able to log into my Mac Developer Account.

I select my Provisioning Profile in the dropdown, and click "Validate".

It comes back with several errors:

1 - "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle {BUNDLENAME} [{BUNDLENAME}.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the Mac OS Developer Portal."

2 - "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value, '{DIFFERENT-BUNDLE-FROM-OTHER-PROJECT}'.  If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect.

3 - Invalid Code Signing Entitlements.  The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provision profile.  The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.applications-identifier' in '{BUNDLENAME}.app/Contents/MacOS/{BUNDLENAME}'

I was able to do the same process before, for a vanilla app, before Mavericks.  I'm not sure if this is a Mavericks error, or a fact that now I have multiple app projects.  Particularly odd is that DIFFERENT-BUNDLE-FROM-OTHER-PROJECT in error (2) is not the same bundle name as the current project's bundle.

Would love any help you can provide!  Thank you!

Comment: I get the same error, on 10.8 wight Xcode 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this was a secret key missing or corruption issue. I ended up revoking the existing certificates and profiles I had in XCode > Preferences > Accounts, and issuing new ones.

Comment: Yep, it did work after that!  I had some odd secret key pairs, which I had to remove in Keychain too.  I just re-created my key pairs in apple, and everything started working after that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set a provisional profile in the Build Settings section.
See here: [Xcode 5: Code signing entitlement errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors)
and here: [Weird code-signing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081995/weird-code-signing-error)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apple Developer Portal, recreate the provisioning profile (distribution profile in your case) and download it again. Make sure that the Distribution certificate is installed in your Keychain Access in order to sign apps submitted for the App Store. and Recheck ur Bundule Id as well

Answer (score -4):

You should try setting up a WildCard Provisioning Profile and go from there.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: Look up how to do it on the Apple Developer Center.  It's really easy to do.