# Missing code-signing certificate when uploading OS X app

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

I am very new on apple app development. I just updated the app for my company and trying to reupload it. But I can't pass the validate on xcode.

I am using xcode 5.01.

Below are my project setting:
   General: 
            Bundle Identifier: com.company_name.program_name.
            Version and Build Are both 1.1
            Signing: Mac App Store.
   Build Settings:
            Code Signing Identity both Debug and Release are chossing Mac Developer
            Provisioning Profile, I tried all of the profiles

I am still getting Invalid Provisioning Profile "Missing code-signing certificate" when validating.

I saw this post
["Invalid Provisioning Profile... [Missing code-signing certificate.]" for brand new, Vanilla Mac App in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574344/invalid-provisioning-profile-missing-code-signing-certificate-for-brand)

But deleting and recreating an account doesn't help. Can anyone help me?