# Code signing entitlements payload error

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I updated an existing iPhone app for iOS7, archived and validated in XCode 5 and get an error I do not understand.

[image: error message]

I unchecked all capabilities, in particular the in-app purchase which I do not need but seemed to be checked by default. Further I did everything as usual.

Any idea what direction I should look to solve this problem?

Comment: It is better to add the text into the post, rather than an image, for parsing, searching and indexing purposes.

Comment: Check out the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @JScarry: thanks, already found that page, but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I ended up ignoring the error, compiled the app with the App Store mobileprovision file, and uploaded using the App Uploader tool (so not from XCode directly). It worked, and the app got accepted for the app store.

So: no explanation, but also no worries ;-)

Comment: I had exactly the same error and I emailed Apple Support. There is a bug in Xcode that affects some developers. Their solution worked for me and is described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386827/code-signing-entitlement-errors-same-error-different-cause