# when i archive with xcode6 ,failed to locate or generate matching signing assets

Tags: ios, provisioning, profiles

questios follows:
No matching provisioning profiles found for "application/lottery.app"
none of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements:application-identifier,beta-reports-active,keychain-acccess-groups.

come to save me,or i will be over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem answer at:[See the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006773/xcode6-error-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-application)

On a side note:

You might want to install [IPhone Config Utility](http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/)

If you want to understand what all the terms like Provisioning, Developer Certificate and Key mean you might want to read this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood). Under the hood its just plain Public-Private key pair based Asymmetric Encryption Operations.