# Xcode Watchkit: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active, com.apple.security.application-groups

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

Yes, I know that there are a lot of these questions floating around and I know that the answer to all of them was:

Log into Developer Member Center

Go to Identifiers, profiles, etc

Click Edit and then Generate on your provisioning profile

That didn't work for me! I developed my application in Xcode 6.4 Beta 1 and with WatchKit. I tried submitting it but after seeing that error, I figured maybe I should try submitting it with a nonbeta version of Xcode. By the way here is that error:

[image: WatchKit Error]

So I went back into Xcode 6.3, the not beta Xcode and tried submitting again. It did the same thing! I then, still in Xcode 6.3, created another projects and just copied and pasted my code into a project that was not made in beta. I kept the same Bundle ID and everything.

I still got the same result. So I have no idea what to do! I've been working on this for a whole day now and the Apple Watch is released in 5 days and I CAN'T MISS THAT!!! So PLEASE help!

I have tried:

Restarting both Beta Xcode and Normal Xcode

Logging out and logging back in again (on Mac desktop I mean)

Doing the normal Developer Portal mumbo jumbo with regenerating the provisioning profile

Creating new project with same code

PLEASE help! I thank you in advance!

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29272260/4206060) tl,dr: get your provisioning profiles set up as required.

Answer (score 24):

I got a similar error when attempting to submit, as below...

```
No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/yourapp.app"
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: 
beta-reports-active, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier.com, 
com.apple.security.application-groups, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers
```

[image]

**Short Answer:**

Remove and re-install your provisioining profiles

**Long Answer:**

When our project is built the appropriate provisioning profiles are installed automatically simply by being copied into the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory.

When the problem occurred I could see that the correct provisioning profiles existed in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` HOWEVER when I opened the 'iPhone Configuration Utility' Mac application the appropriate provisioning profiles were NOT appearing (which I guess is an indication that they aren't properly installed, maybe coz they're corrupted or something)

I have no idea how it got iteslf in this state but I was able to fix by deleting the existing files in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory, re-building the app so that the provisioning profiles were copied back into the directory forcing them to be reinstalled.

The provisioning profiles then became visible in iPhone Configuration Utiltiy and when submitting to the App Store this error no longer appeared.

Comment: not working. any other solutions?

Comment: @MihirOza I am not sure, but you can try to remove the profile from Apple Developer Member Center, if you've downloaded it and imported to your auth chain.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting all files in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder worked for me.

Comment: Any luck @charles.cc.hsu ?