# No matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode6, archive

Im having a problem archiving my app to submit it as a build in iTunes connect. When I try archiving it, it succeeds but when try submitting it I get this error message: [image]

I think it has something to do with an iCloud issue or maybe a watch kit extension issue but I tried everything and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me!

Comment: _I tried everything_ - Can you be more specific so that people trying to answer won't post something you've already tried?

Comment: Also: Is this a personal account or is this a company account where you have to go to someone else to have a provisioning profile created?

Comment: Check the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006773/xcode6-error-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-application