# iOS codesign error "No matching provisioning profiles found"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

When I try to archive my xcode project for the App Store I get the following error:

```
No matching provisioning profiles found: This product type must be built using a provisioning profile, however no provisioning profile matching both the identity “iPhone Distribution: Thomas Hoek (**********)” and the bundle identifier “FutureGame.myApp” was found.
```

How can I fix this?
I have never uploaded a app to the app store before so please be very clear and descriptive!

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006773/xcode6-error-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-application and try to search before asking a question :)

Comment: i already checked that post :) but my files look way different and the solution given there didnt work :(

Comment: Just click on "fix issue" when this message appears

Comment: there is no fix issue button :(

Comment: On the general tab in project settings you will be getting a warning and a fix issue button right below "Team" click on that

Comment: in project settings i only see a tab called info and a tab called build settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111293/discussion-between-ahmad-ishfaq-and-futurecake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the general tab in project settings you will be getting a warning and a fix issue button right below "Team" click on that, xcode will take care the rest for you.