# Submitting iOS app to app store invalid code signing entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, code-signing, bundle-identifier

I'm desperate! I have a deadline and I can not post! Please someone help me
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5: Code signing entitlement errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Joe Regan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82798/joe-regan) from [possible duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors):

> 1. Xcode Preferences
> 2. Accounts tab
> 3. Select your Apple ID
> 4. Hit the View Details button in the Apple ID detail panel
> 5. Hit the Refresh button in the lower left corner

---

This post from the iOS Developer Library may also help you:

[Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html)

Comment: I follow your guide, but now I have this error: "iTunes store operation failed: “Error Description not available”

Comment: is absurd ! I'm losing a lot of time behind this thing

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue when i try to make ipa file for App Store.
- only you have to check whether "Any iOS SDK" is selected or "Any OS X SDK" is selected in Build settings?

If you have selected "Any iOS SDK" then it will always shows this error message again and again in new XCode. So, go to your app->Target->Code Siging-> and remove "Any iOS SDK" and select "Any OS X SDK".

follow same process for Project section also. Now, clean and rebuild your project. It will be done.