# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements for push notification (ITMS 90046)

Tags: xcode

I am getting an error when trying to submit an update to my iPhone app through Application Loader. I have not changed anything in the configuration since I did the last update, so I am not sure why it's complaining now.

I have tried refreshing my provisioning profiles in Xcode and also tried to explicitly set the Provisioning Profile in project's Build Settings. When explicitly set the Provisioning Profile in Build Setting and then do Archive, Xcode complains that "No matching code signing identities" for the selected provisioning profile were found. When I do Fix Issue, Xcode resets the Provisioning Profile in Build Settings back to Automatic and Code Signing Identity to iPhone Developer.

I have also tried to do a clean build, Alt + Clean to clean the build folder, restarted Xcode multiple times, and did a Delete on Derived Data in Organizer > Projects, but nothing has helped.

"ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your applications bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'development' for key 'aps-environment' in '...' is not supported."

When I try to submit the Archive after Xcode automatically resets Code Signing Identity to iPhone Developer, I get the following error.

I could try to revoke the Distribution certificate, but I am not sure what's the consequences will be. On Apple's website it says that revoking a certificate doesn't impact existing apps in the store, but I am concerned if there are any other unintended impact of this that I haven't thought about.

"Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets: Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues -- Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate. If you have your signing identity on another Mac, you can import a developer profile. You can also revoke the current certificate and request one again."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors?rq=1  - Hint: restart Xcode

Answer (score 11):

Try to do a Product->Clean and then make sure that the Provisioning profile and Code signing identities are correct.

[image: code signing details]

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem because I tried to chnage the bundle id many time during development. It was solve with check the build setting>product bundle identifier and correct the name same as bundle id. I think the xcode not replace this new the newest bundle id. I hope this help

Answer (score -1):

While ideally Xcode should figure this out automatically and override the default 'development' aps-enviroment, in reality it often doesn't work.

The easiest way out of this nightmare is to copy your entitlements file, name it Release.entitlements – and make it known to the build settings.

This fixed it for me.