# Two errors -- binary not optimized for iphone 5 (error 90096) and invalid code signing (error 90163) --when submitting to iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, air, code-signing, testflight

I have two issues when I upload to iTunes and I’m not sure if they are related to each other:

1. **ERROR ITMS- 90096: “Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 ……”**
   This is weird because I have the correct splash screen included
   which is Default-568h@2x with the file size being 640 x 1136. Not
   sure why I’m getting this error.
2. **ERROR ITMS- 90096: “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements**. The
   entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that
   are contained in the provisioning file. The bundle contains a key
   that is not included in the provi…… “beta-reports-active”. I know
   that this issue is being caused by the
   beta-reports-active  tag. I’ve researched this issue but
   have not found anything that definitively solves this problem. For
   this building I’m using a production certificate and provisioning
   profile. I am attempting to upload the app for TestFlight App so I
   need to solve this problem.

My development environment is Animate (Flash) 2015, win10, AIR 20.0.

I’m in desperate need of help as I’ve had this issue for a while now and I can’t find any sources that solve this problem (invalid code signing).

Please help!!!!! I would appreciate input on either of the issues.

Comment: -->Check all those images are .PNG format
-->Put those images at root level of your project
-->Add another splash.png with name "Default-568h@2x.png" for iPhone 5. Its size should be 640 × 1136 pixel.

Comment: refer this link --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818381/xcode-5-code-signing-entitlement-errors

Comment: Thanks! #1) The ERROR ITMS- 90096: “Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 ……” is SOLVED! I had my splash images in a folder. Once I took them out of the folder and put them in the same directory as the project I was didn't receive the error anymore. One problem down, one to go!

Comment: The problem for the  "ERROR ITMS- 90163: “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements" error was that a development AND production provisioning profile was using the same App ID. Once I created and paired a separate app ID for the development and production provisioning profile the problem was solved. PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: welcome Baker. well done.

Answer (score 1):

ERROR ITMS- 90096: “Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

**Solution:**

-->Check all those images are .PNG format -->Put those images at root level of your project